# Adding columns to DataFrame extracted from string expression

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a column `keyboardInfo` containing strings as follows

```
keyboardInfo
[alphabet de_CH:swiss 1080x667 text actionNone isMultiLine]
[alphabet de_CH:swiss 1080x667 text actionNone isMultiLine]
[alphabetAutomaticShifted de_CH:swiss 1080x667 text actionNone isMultiLine]
[alphabet de_CH:swiss 720x440 text actionNone isMultiLine]
```

The DataFrame is pretty big (around 5'000'000 rows). The third entry of each string (after the second white space) is always the width x height (but in total the string can contain different amounts of elements, that means it should be counted from the left). Now, I would like to add two additional columns to the DataFrame containing the width and height (as integers). The results should look as follows (the DataFrame contains also other columns which I droped here):

```
keyboardInfo                                                                    width    height
[alphabet de_CH:swiss 1080x667 text actionNone isMultiLine]                     1080     667
[alphabet de_CH:swiss 1080x667 text actionNone isMultiLine]                     1080     667
[alphabetAutomaticShifted de_CH:swiss 1080x667 text actionNone isMultiLine]     1080     667
[alphabet de_CH:swiss 720x440 text actionNone isMultiLine]                      720      440
```

How can this be done efficiently?

Comment: Are there more numbers in the text besides the width and the height?

Comment: @Erfan Most likely not but it is safer to split according to white spaces I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: `split`, first we get the third element, then we split on the `x`:

```
df[['width', 'height']] = df['keyboardInfo'].str.split().str[2].str.split('x', expand=True)
```

Option 2: Use `str.extractall` to get the numbers, then use `unstack`:

```
df[['width', 'height']] = df['keyboardInfo'].str.extractall("(\d+)").unstack()
```

Output:

```
                                        keyboardInfo width height
0  [alphabet de_CH:swiss 1080x667 text actionNone...  1080    667
1  [alphabet de_CH:swiss 1080x667 text actionNone...  1080    667
2  [alphabetAutomaticShifted de_CH:swiss 1080x667...  1080    667
3  [alphabet de_CH:swiss 720x440 text actionNone ...   720    440
```